Coloured headings in margins
In my CV design, I like to put some sections in the margins in order to make better use of the space. Currently, I’m using a solution based on tcolorbox, but I would like to get rid of the reliance on that package and do it all “manually” instead.
My issue is related to headings inside the margins. I like to use a centered heading with a slightly darker background than the surroundings. But I would like these headings to fill out the same horizontal space as the coloured bacground, i.e. from x = -1cm to x = 6cm. (The choice to start at x = -1cm is because some PDF viewers will otherwise show a white line to the left of the page.) I tried using a solution based on this answer. But as you see, the dark red area only fills out the text area, not the entire area from -1cm to 6cm.
Bonus question: Is it bad practice to use shipout/background to add a minipage to the margins like this?
Note: I have used TikZ-based solutions previously. However, due to some rounding number stuff, some PDF viewers will show a TikZ rectangle as protruding the coloured background at certain zoom levels. For that reason, I prefer non-TikZ solutions, e.g. something that boils down to a simple \rule.
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage{calc} % For length calculations

\setlrmargins{7cm}{*}{*}
\setulmarginsandblock{2.0cm}{*}{1}
\checkandfixthelayout

\AddToHook{shipout/background}{%
    \put(-1cm, -\paperheight-1cm) {%
        \textcolor{red}{\rule{7cm}{\paperheight+2cm}}%
    }
}

\newcommand\marginsection[1]{%
    \vspace*{5pt}%
    \colorbox{red!70!black}{%
        \begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
            \begin{center}
                #1
            \end{center}
        \end{minipage}%
    }%
    \vspace*{5pt}%
}

\begin{document}

\AddToHookNext{shipout/background}{%
    \put(.5cm, -.5cm){%
        \begin{minipage}[t][\paperheight-1cm][t]{5cm}
            \color{white}
            Hello World.
            
            \marginsection{A section}
            
            More hello world.
        \end{minipage}
    }
}


Hello World


\end{document}


What I want instead:


\rlap inside \put` isn't needed.

@egreg Can’t I tempt you with a bounty?

It is not bad practice to place boxes using shipout/background I would say. It just depends on what you want to do. You want to place things absolutely on the page, and to this end, I would consider this approach totally valid.

Why not just adjusting the spacing using \hspace? Also, I would probably just use \centering here.
Note that the horizontal spacing for the darker is such that it has a bleed of 1 cm to the left (like the red background) and adjusts for the \fboxsep which is the padding inside the \colorbox.
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{calc} % For length calculations

\setlrmargins{7cm}{*}{*}
\setulmarginsandblock{2.0cm}{*}{1}
\checkandfixthelayout

\AddToHook{shipout/background}{%
    \put(-1cm, -\paperheight-1cm) {%
        \textcolor{red}{\rule{7cm}{\paperheight+2cm}}%
    }
}

\newcommand\marginsection[1]{%
    \vspace*{5pt}%
    \hspace{-1.5cm}%
    \colorbox{red!70!black}{%
        \hspace{1.5cm-\fboxsep}%
        \begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
            \centering #1
        \end{minipage}%
        \hspace{.5cm-\fboxsep}%
    }%
    \vspace*{5pt}%
}

\begin{document}

\AddToHookNext{shipout/background}{%
    \put(.5cm, -.5cm){%
        \begin{minipage}[t][\paperheight-1cm][t]{5cm}
            \color{white}
            Hello World.
            
            \marginsection{A section}
            
            More hello world.
        \end{minipage}
    }
}


Hello World


\end{document}



Or maybe use the l3draw package with coffins which allows you to adjust everything in an even more ganular way:
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{l3draw} 

\setlrmargins{7cm}{*}{*}
\setulmarginsandblock{2.0cm}{*}{1}
\checkandfixthelayout

\ExplSyntaxOn
\AddToHook { shipout/background } {
    \draw_begin:
        \bool_set_false:N \l_draw_bb_update_bool
        \color_select:n { red }
        \draw_path_rectangle_corners:nn { -1cm , -\paperheight - 1cm } { 6cm , \paperheight + 1cm }
        \draw_path_use_clear:n { fill }
    \draw_end:
}

\NewDocumentCommand { \marginsection } { m } {
    \vspace*{5pt}
    \draw_begin:
        \bool_set_false:N \l_draw_bb_update_bool
        \draw_scope_begin:
            \color_select:n { red!50!black }
            \draw_path_rectangle:nn { -1.5cm , -6pt } { 7cm , \baselineskip + 6pt }
            \draw_path_use_clear:n { fill }
        \draw_scope_end:
        \color_select:n { white }
        \vcoffin_set:Nnn \l_tmpa_coffin { \linewidth } { \centering #1 }
        \draw_transform_shift:n { 0cm , 0.5 * ( \baselineskip - 6pt ) }
        \draw_coffin_use:Nnn \l_tmpa_coffin { vc } { l }
    \draw_end:
    \vspace*{5pt}
}

\NewDocumentEnvironment { margintext } { +b } {
    \AddToHookNext { shipout/background } {
        \draw_begin:
            \bool_set_false:N \l_draw_bb_update_bool
            \color_select:n { white }
            \vcoffin_set:Nnn \l_tmpa_coffin { 5cm } { #1 }
            \draw_transform_shift:n { .5cm , -.5cm }
            \draw_coffin_use:Nnn \l_tmpa_coffin { t } { l }
        \draw_end:
    }
} { }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\begin{margintext}
    Hello World.
                
    \marginsection{A section}
    
    More hello world.
\end{margintext}

Hello World

\end{document}

Same output (more or less) as above.

Note that there is also shipout/foreground which you could also use depending on the desired outcome.

This looks like more or less exactly what I was looking for!  However, there is an issue with that last solution: If I remove the \marginsection, then the text in the margintext protrudes out of the page.

@Gaussler But only in the second version, right? I‘ll check later

Yes, only in the second one.

@Gaussler Second code example should work now.

Thanks! By the way, I have a follow-up question in case you want more reputation points.

Too big for a comment (and to preserve the format).
\AddToHook{shipout/background}{%
    \put(0pt, -\paperheight) {%
        \textcolor{red}{\rule{7cm}{\paperheight}}%
    }%
}

works fine for me.  Note that your code adds a space before the start of \rule.

Thanks, updated the question. I actually had these comments in my original example, but apparently I forgot them in my MWE. Also, the \rlap is there because I also use a similar construction where the coloured margin is on the right, and then \llap makes everything a lot prettier.

\llap makes sense it you are starting on the right side.  The alternative is to \put to the left side and use something like \makebox[\paperwidth][r]{...}.  Now if you want to do both in one put, \rlap would be useful.
